# Add a domain user into a local group when the domain is not available

Tags: windows, windows-7, active-directory

I have a PC (Windows 7) that has a domain user. Because of some maintenance issues the PC is not in the company that has the domain user. There is no access to the domain through the internet.

I need to add this domain user into one of the local groups. I tried to to this by means of the Local Users and Groups panel of the Windows. It was not possible of course. Location of the user is only the local PC, domain is not accessible. As the local admin account I have also tried command line

```
net localgroup "My Group" Domain\user1 /add
```

However this also did not work. Is there any way to add a domain user into a local group when the domain is not available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not without joining the computer to the domain containing the domain user to add locally or at least to a domain for which a trust exists with the domain containing the user to add locally.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739265(v=ws.10).aspx

• If the computer is joined to a domain, you can add user accounts, computer accounts, and group accounts from that domain and from trusted domains to a local group.